# Issue running Fla UI test cases using Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, flaui

I am currently writing automated test cases using Fla UI. When running the test cases using ADO pipeline, getting an error "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

When we do RDP for the machine and running the test case using Pipeline->test were running fine. But when we disconnect or ran keep alive script, tests are not running through pipeline.

We are now struck running test cases from pipeline. We are looking help in running Fla Ui automated tests from Azure pipelines. Can some one guide us in resolving this issue.